# Problems with controlling the placement of Dockpanel control in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application with tabs and browser navigation controls. I'd like the tabs to be on top of the navigation display but the navigation is only shown, not the tabs, as show here; only the navigation bar is being displayed:

[image]

This is the xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                <DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                        <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                        </Button>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Content="&lt;Back" Name ="backree" Click="backree_Click"> </Button>
            <Button Content="Go" Name ="navixd" Click="navixd_Click"></Button>
            <Button Content="Forward&gt;" Name ="forwardyikes" Click="forwardyikes_Click"></Button>
            <TextBox Name="addbox"></TextBox>
        </DockPanel>
        <cefsharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Address="StackOverflow.com" FrameLoadEnd="ChromiumWebBrowser_OnFrameLoadEnd" Name="Browser"></cefsharp:ChromiumWebBrowser>
    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

How would I make the navigation bar be displayed below the tabs, or even better how would I display the tabs in the very top of the window like chrome tabs, (im not sure what this part is called).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't defined the `Grid` Rows and Columns, add this to the Grid Definition

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="0"> [...] </TabControl>
    <DockPanel  Grid.Row="1"> [...] </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

This will force the controls to order into different rows.

This `Height="auto"` means that your row will shrink to the minimum height possible. `Height="*"` instead will use all the space left.

To be able to have the tabs at the top of the window (as in Chrome) you probably need more work, with the help of supplements packets or own implemented windows.

I hope I was helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, it worked. I know that this isn't really related to the question but do you know how i could have a different browser page displayed for each tab? And again, thank you!